# Boolean difference not showing in render

Tags: rendering, modifiers

I used an array of rectangles and a difference boolean modifier to cut a shape, but when I disable the rectangles in renders it removes the boolean effect. [Here's the file](https://pasteall.org/blend/08a69da6ea2b4823bbe1fc633cf7af88)

The model
[image: The model]

How I want it to look
[image: How I want it to look]

How it renders
[image: How it renders]

Comment: Hello could you please share your file? (only the sphere and the rectangles) https://pasteall.org/blend/

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Just apply the boolean modifier, then it works.

---

Update:

Of course Moonboots answer is totally right too - just press that render visibility button and it works without applying.

But one thing i have to say:

To all the downvoters of my answer: I didn't say "you have to" or "you must". I just provided an answer which works. Yes, there are other answer possible. Yes, Moonboots answer works non-destructive. Did the OP asks for a non-destructive solution? No. Did my answer helped him? Yes. Did my answer solved his problem? yes. Did he give me the answer check? Yes. Are the downvoters just jealous and cannot face reality? FOR SURE!
Did i try to delete the answer? Yes. But Stackexchange won't let me. But after some thoughts...yep, my answer is right. Maybe not the best but it WORKS.

Comment: Oh, that works thanks. Had no idea you had to do that.

Comment: @Axiom You don't have to apply the modifier for it to be visible.  See the other answer for a non-destructive way to use the modifier in a render.  It is _never_ necessary to apply a modifier before it will appear in a render.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you have disabled the visibility of the modifier for render:

[image]